# Не заменяет в db пароль пользователя.

Tags: база-данных, php

При изменение востановления пароля на почту приходит сообщение с паролем, но в базе данных не изменяется.

Письмо на почте: http://i076.radikal.ru/1302/a9/e6e52c355fd5.gif
База данных: http://s006.radikal.ru/i214/1302/be/2c4071f77028.gif

```
> <?php include_once('connectdb.php');
> ?> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
> HTML 4.01//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <html>  <head>   <meta
> http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html;
> charset=windows-1251">  
> <title>Восстановление пароля</title>
> 
> </head> <body>
> 
> <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
>   $name = $_POST['name'];     $email =
> $_POST['email'];      if (empty($name)){
>       echo "Введите имя!";    }   elseif
> (empty($email)){      echo "Введите
> e-mail!";     }    else{      $resultat =
> mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE
> name = '$name' AND email = '$email'");
>       $array =
> mysql_fetch_array($resultat);         if
> (empty($array)){          echo 'Ошибка!
> Такого пользователя не существует';
>       }       elseif
> (mysql_num_rows($resultat) > 0){
>           $chars="qazxswedcvfrtgbnhyujmkiolp1234567890QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP";
>           $max=10; 
>           $size=StrLen($chars)-1; 
>           $password=null; 
>                       while($max--){          $password.=$chars[rand(0,$size)]; 
>           }           $newmdPassword =
> md5($password);           $title =
> 'Востановления пароля пользователю
> '.$name.' для сайта
> http://bonline.16mb.com!';            $headers
> = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251\r\n";           $headers
> .= "Админестрация сайта
> http://bonline.16mb.com";             $letter =
>   'Вы запросили восстановление пароля
> для аккаунта '.$name.' на сайте
> http://bonline.16mb.com \r\nВаш новый
> пароль: '.$password;
> 
> // Отправляем письмо          if
> (mail($email, $title, $letter,
> $headers)) {
>              mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$newmdPassword' WHERE name
> = '$name'  AND users.email = '$email'");
>              echo 'Новый пароль отправлен на ваш e-mail!<br><a
> href="index.php">Главная
> страница</a>';            }       }           } }
> mysql_close(); ?>
> 
> <table>
>  
>       <form method="POST">
>       <tr>
>       <td>Логин:</td>
>       <td><input type="text" size="20" name="name" ></td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>       <td>E-mail:</td>
>       <td><input type="text" size="20" name="email"></td>
>       </tr>
>       <tr>
>        <td></td>
>       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Восстановить
> пароль" name="submit" ></td>
>       </tr>
>      <br>
>       </form> </table> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обновляйте пароль по id пользователя, а не по логину и почте.

В текущей реализации не обновляет из-за строки users.email в запросе с UPDATE, должно быть email.

Переменные получаемые из $_POST[], нужно обезопасить, наприрмер, используя mysql_real_escape_string(), иначе совсем не безопасно получается.

Слово Админ**и**страция пишется через **И**

Во**сс**тановление, с двумя буквами **С**

Comment: С орфографией проблема((
Щас проверю, может работает)

Comment: не работает(